# Javascript date delta conversion to and from string

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I am trying to extract year, month and days data from the string `1 year, 5 months and 4 days`.

Similarly, I want to be able to convert 1/2/4 into `1 year, 2 months and 4 days`

In both case, I would like to handle `day vs days` or remove days if they are 0.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Read about javascript regular expression functions, i.e. `String.match()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with callback

```js
function format(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, function(m, m1, m2, m3) {
    var s = [];
    if (m1 != 0)
      s.push(m1 + (m1 == 1 ? ' year' : ' years'));
    if (m2 != 0)
      s.push(m2 + (m2 == 1 ? ' month' : ' months'))
    if (m3 != 0)
      s.push(m3 + (m3 == 1 ? ' day' : ' days'))
    if (s.length == 3)
      return s[0] + ', ' + s[1] + ' and ' + s[2];
    else if (s.length == 2)
      return s[0] + ' and ' + s[1];
    else
      return s[0];
  })
}
document.write(format('1/2/4') +
  '<br>' + format('1/2/0') +
  '<br>' + format('0/2/0') +
  '<br>' + format('1/2/4') +
  '<br>' + format('2/2/4') +
  '<br>' + format('1/21/0') +
  '<br>' + format('0/2/1') +
  '<br>' + format('1/1/1'));
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/nS7xR7/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**UPDATE :**
Reverse can be done  as following using **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** and **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

```js
function formatRev(str) {
  return str.replace(/^(?:(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*)?(\d+)\s+(\w+)(?:\s+and\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+))?$/ig, function(m, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6) {
    var s = [0, 0, 0];
    s[extract(m2)] = m1;
    s[extract(m4)] = m3;
    s[extract(m6)] = m5;
    return s.join('/');
  })
}

function extract(str) {
  if (/year/.test(str))
    return 0;
  else if (/month/.test(str))
    return 1;
  else if (/day/.test(str))
    return 2;
  else
    return null;
}

document.write(formatRev('5 years and 4 days') +
  '<br>' + formatRev('1 year and 2 months') +
  '<br>' + formatRev('2 months') +
  '<br>' + formatRev('1 year, 2 months and 4 days')
);
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/bI2eN7/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks :D What's the best way to extract it in reverse? Eg: `1 year and 3 days`. I am currently using split and lots of if-else , anything more elegant you can suggest?

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar Try `(?:(\d+) years?)?\s*(?:(\d+) months?)?\s*(?:(\d+) days?)?` Not sure if this will help.